How to intercept methods using DispatchProxy which signed custom attribute?
I want to intercept method using my DispathProxy. So I created a custom proxy class like following.
    public abstract class InterceptorProxy<T>: DispatchProxy
    {
        private T? _decorated;
        
        protected override object? Invoke(MethodInfo? targetMethod, object?[]? args)
        {
            try
            {
                OnBefore(targetMethod,args);
                
                var result = targetMethod?.Invoke(_decorated, args);
                
                OnAfter(targetMethod, args, result);
                
                return result;
            }
            catch (TargetInvocationException e)
            {
                OnException(targetMethod, args, e);
                throw;
            }
        }
        
        public static T? Create(T decorated)
        {
            object? proxy = Create<T, InterceptorProxy<T>>();
            ((InterceptorProxy<T>)proxy!)?.SetParameters(decorated);

            return (T)proxy!;
        }
        
        private void SetParameters(T decorated)
        {
            _decorated = decorated ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(decorated));
        }
        
        protected virtual void OnException(MethodInfo? methodInfo, object?[]? args, Exception exception) { }
        protected virtual void OnAfter(MethodInfo? methodInfo, object?[]? args, object? result) { }
        protected virtual void OnBefore(MethodInfo? methodInfo, object?[]? args) { }
    }

And I have a custom attribute to sign my methods.
public class DispachedAttribute : Attribute
{
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public DispatchedAttribute(string type)
    {
        Type = type;
    }
}

And I want to intercept the methods that only signed with this attribute.
in controller:
[Dispached("POST")]
public ResponseDTO Run(RequestDTO requestDTO)
{
    var result = service.Get(requestDTO);
    return result;
}

in any class:
public class myclass{
  [Dispached("Do")]
  public string Run(string param)
  {
    // do something
    return param;
  }
}

My interceptor should automatically work when this method run. How can I do this?

Do you want to intercept this method with the [Dispached("POST")] attribute from the onbefore method, or do you want to separate it from the onbefore method and implement it directly in InterceptorProxy?

I can create LogInterceptor derived from InterceptorProxy class. I do not use Dispatched(POST) in attribute. I can use IServiceCollection extension to select and apply to execute methods that signed by Dispatched attribute. But how?

Since the DispatchProxy.Create method requires the creation of an instance of TProxy, if TProxy is abstract, then the instance cannot be created. The following error occurs:

If you want to use the DispatchProxy.Create<T, TProxy>() method, you may want to make sure that TProxy is a non-abstract class, Here's an example you can use as a reference:
You can use GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DispachedAttribute), false) to get the custom attributes (Attributes) associated with the specified type (DispachedAttribute), and implement method interception by throwing an exception.
   public class InterceptorProxy<T> : DispatchProxy
{
    private T? _decorated;

    protected override object? Invoke(MethodInfo? targetMethod, object?[]? args)
    {
        try
        {
            var attributes = targetMethod?.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DispachedAttribute), false);
            if (attributes != null && attributes.Length > 0)
            {

                throw new InvalidOperationException("This method marked with DisallowInterceptAttribute");

            }

            var result = targetMethod?.Invoke(_decorated, args);

            return result;
        }
        catch (TargetInvocationException e)
        {
            OnException(targetMethod, args, e);
            throw;
        }
    }

    public static T? Create(T decorated)
    {
        object? proxy = Create<T, InterceptorProxy<T>>();
        ((InterceptorProxy<T>)proxy!)?.SetParameters(decorated);

        return (T)proxy!;
    }

    private void SetParameters(T decorated)
    {
        _decorated = decorated ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(decorated));
    }

    protected virtual void OnException(MethodInfo? methodInfo, object?[]? args, Exception exception) { }
        
}

My service:
public interface IMyService
{
    [Dispached("POST")]
    void DoSomething();
}
public class MyService : IMyService
{
       
    public void DoSomething()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Doing something...");
    }
}

Controller:
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly IMyService _myService;

    public HomeController()
    {
        _myService = InterceptorProxy<IMyService>.Create(new MyService());
    }

    [HttpPost]
       
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        _myService.DoSomething();
        return Ok("OKK");
    }
}

When I use method with custom properties, will throw my custom exception information:

